# PyMongo upsert throws "upsert must be an instance of bool" error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm running an update on my MongoDB from Python. I have this line:

```
self.word_counts[source].update({'date':posttime},{"$inc" : words},{'upsert':True})
```

But it throws this error:

```
raise TypeError("upsert must be an instance of bool")
```

But `True` looks like an instance of bool to me!

How should I correctly write this update?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The third argument to PyMongo's [`update()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) is `upsert` and must be passed a boolean, not a dictionary. Change your code to:

```
self.word_counts[source].update({'date':posttime}, {"$inc" : words}, True)
```

Or pass `upsert=True` as a keyword argument:

```
self.word_counts[source].update({'date':posttime}, {"$inc" : words}, upsert=True)
```

Your mistake was likely caused by reading about `update()` in the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update). The JavaScript version of `update` takes an object as its third argument containing optional parameters like `upsert` and `multi`. But since Python allows passing keyword arguments to a function (unlike JavaScript which only has positional arguments), this is unnecessary and PyMongo takes these options as optional function parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks, apparently the example I was working off of was incorrect.

Comment: db.<collection_name>.update( {<filters>}, {<update_value>}, upsert=False)                               

pymongo version = pymongo==3.11.0

this is work for me try :)

Answer (score 17):

According to http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.3/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update you should indeed pass upsert as a keyword rather than just True, that is

```
self.word_counts[source].update({'date':posttime},{"$inc" : words},**{'upsert':True})
```

Or

```
self.word_counts[source].update({'date':posttime},{"$inc" : words},upsert=True)
```

is a better approach than just passing True as if you ever wish to pass other kwargs such as `safe` or `multi` code might break if order of args is not kept.

Answer (score 4):

upsert should be passed as either positional parameter, like so

```
self.word_counts[source].update(
    {'date':posttime},
    {"$inc" : words},
    True)
```

or as a keyword argument, like so

```
self.word_counts[source].update(
    {'date':posttime},
    {"$inc" : words},
    upsert=True)
```