# MongoDB with python - two actions in one query

Tags: python, mongodb

i try to alter an document with 2 operations in one query:

```
_userstats.update(
    {"nick" : nick},
    {"$set" : {"online" : True}},
    {"$inc" : {"joined" : 1}})
```

But when i try this, i get en error:

```
raise TypeError("upsert must be an instance of bool")
TypeError: upsert must be an instance of bool
```

I dont get this to work.
Can someone please help me to figure out what exactly my fault is?

Comment: You can find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055797/pymongo-upsert-throws-upsert-must-be-an-instance-of-bool-error-is-this-a-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all update operations in one dictionary passed as second argument to [`update`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update):

```
_userstats.update(
    {"nick" : nick},
    {"$set" : {"online" : True}, "$inc" : {"joined" : 1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the second operation as a third argument, which is not the way `update` function works. You should put all the operations in one object. Try this:

```
_userstats.update(
    {"nick" : nick},
    {{"$set" : {"online" : True}},
     {"$inc" : {"joined" : 1}}})
```