# How do I do a get_or_create in pymongo (python mongodb)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

First, find if a document matching query exists.

If so, update that document with the new data.

Otherwise, insert a new document into the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Insert if not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists)?

Comment: not homework but unable to read basic documentation....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use "upsert" equal to true.
Then the update query you run with "upsert" as true will do exactly what you want.

- update if exists.
- insert new if it does not exist.

From MongoDb documentation:

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )

Arguments:

    criteria - query which selects the record to update;
    objNew - updated object or $ operators (e.g., $inc) which manipulate the object
    upsert - if this should be an "upsert"; that is, if the record does not exist, insert it
    multi - if all documents matching criteria should be updated
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Example:

```
db.test.update({"x": "42"}, {"$set": {"a": "21"}},True)    
#True => Upsert is True
```

See "update" documentation here :

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html

Comment: `update` only returns a `WriteResult`. Use `findAndModify` instead.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update

Set upsert=True

Answer (score 0):

Full test example. Also see [$setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) which unlike [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) will not alter the record if the key exists.

```
payload= {'id':'key123','other':'stuff'}
collection.update({'eventid':payload['id']}, {"$set": payload}, upsert=True)
collection.count_documents({}) # 1

payload= {'id':'key123','other':'stuff2'}
collection.update({'eventid':payload['id']}, {"$set": payload}, upsert=True)
collection.count_documents({}) # 1

payload= {'id':'key456','other':'more stuff'}
collection.update({'eventid':payload['id']}, {"$setOnInsert": payload}, upsert=True)
collection.count_documents({}) # 2

payload= {'id':'key456','other':'more stuff2'}
collection.update({'eventid':payload['id']}, {"$setOnInsert": payload}, upsert=True)
collection.count_documents({})
```