# How to do "insert if not exist else update" with mongoengine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm working with mongoengine in Django,
this is my document defination:

```
class Location(mongoengine.Document):  
    user_id = mongoengine.IntField(required=True)  
    point = mongoengine.GeoPointField(required=True)
```

I want to do this:
given a `user_id` and a `point`:
if there is no document that have this `user_id`, create one with the `user_id` and `point` and save it;
else update the document with `user_id` with `point`.
Can I do this in one statement with mongoengine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb: insert if not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists) - The answer is: use `upsert`.

Comment: @mac I think there maybe something even simpler.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Note that `get_or_create` is now scheduled to be deprecated, because with no transaction support in MongoDB it cannot ensure atomicity.

The preferred way is [update](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update) with upsert:

```
Location.objects(user_id=user_id).update_one(set__point=point, upsert=True)
```

More on upserts on the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag).

Comment: How can I do the same thing but with ```user_id==-1``` when the object does not exist?

Comment: @arthur.sw with MongoDB, the object ID for a new document is generated client-side, so you just need to create a new ID with `user_id= ObjectId()`.

Comment: There is a new way to do it since version 0.9 (explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25863633/719276)):

    location = Location.objects(user_id=user_id).modify(upsert=True, new=True, set__point=point)

Comment: There is `upsert_one` method too: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.upsert_one

Answer (score 8):

There is a new way to do it since version 0.9 (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863633/719276)):

```
location = Location.objects(user_id=user_id).modify(upsert=True, new=True, set__point=point)
```

It returns the created or updated object.

Answer (score 5):

this is what I came up with:

```
location = Location.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)[0]  
location.point = point  
location.save()
```

Comment: `location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)`

Is the preferred way of doing it!  But yes that will do what you need!

Comment: `get_or_create()` is now [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongoengine-users/U_1t2eYJqCA/discussion).  `upsert` is [recommended](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongoengine-users/C-i7tKkjPg8/discussion) by the Mongoengine crew.  See @NCao's answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add a method to your class object via:

```
class Location(mongoengine.Document):  
    user_id = mongoengine.IntField(required=True)  
    point = mongoengine.GeoPointField(required=True)

    def register(self):
        # if doesnt exist, create user id and point field
        if not Location.objects(user_id=self.user_id):
            self.user_id = self.user_id
            self.point = self.point
            self.save()
            return True
        # does exist, do nothing
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: What's the reason for the lines
`self.user_id = self.user_id
self.point = self.point`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution to update of not exist was this:

```
    def upsert(self, data: dict, query: dict):
        try:
            sets = {}
            for key in data.keys():
                sets[f"set__{key}"] = data[key]
            response = self.model.objects(**query).update_one(upsert=True, **sets)
            return response
        except Exception as ex:
            # Logger(str(ex)).log_error()
            return False
```

or if you want, you can use the method `update`.