# MongoEngine: Replacing get_or_create with upsert/update_one

Tags: django, mongoengine

I understand that `get_or_create` is now deprecated in favour of using `upsert`, but how do I make `update_one` to return the object rather the number of objects modified, and can I just retrieve an object if I don't want to update anything?

e.g.

```
Model.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', last_name='Potter', age=40)
# assuming that first_name + last_name + age are enough to uniquiely indentify a person
```

returns a Model object (a new object if it didn't exist, and existing object if it does). What would be the equivalent of this using the new method?

```
Model.objects(first_name='John', last_name='Potter', age=40).update_one(upsert=True)
# returns number of objects (1)
Model.objects(first_name='John', last_name='Potter', age=40).update_one(set__first_name='John', set__last_name='Potter', set__age=40,upsert=True)
# returns number of objects (1)
```

Is there a way to make it return the object, and make it behave exactly like `get_or_create`?

I couldn't find how to do this in the [documentation](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update_one)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are very close but you need to use a findAndModify command via [modify](http://mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.modify) rather than an update command.

```
NewDoc = Model.objects(first_name='John', 
                       last_name='Potter', 
                       age=40).modify(upsert=True, new=True,
                                      set__first_name='John, 
                                      set__last_name='Potter', 
                                      set__age=40,
                                      set_on_insert__newUser=True)
```

Take note of the first 2 modify kwargs - `upsert` and `new`. Also take note of the [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert) operator example which will only set a field if the findAndModify does an upsert.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do you have any idea why do I get a `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'modify'`?

Comment: Oh it seems the `modify` command has been made available since 0.9, but the lastest pip version appears to be 0.8.7

Comment: You'll have to install from master via pip. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch

Comment: @Ross so to determine if it's a new doc, I have to create `newUser` field only for this purpose? Looks like an ugly hack, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`modify`](http://mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.modify). Passing a `new=True` you'll get the updated object (or document, in mongodb parlance).