# How to continue insertion after duplicate key error using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

If I need to insert a document in MongoDB if it does not exist yet

```
db_stock.update_one(document, {'$set': document}, upsert=True)
```

.will do the job (feel free to correct me if I am wrong)

But if I have a list of documents and want to insert them all what would be a best way of doing it?

There is a single-record version of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists) but I need an en mass version of it, so it's different.

Let me reword my question. I have millions of documents, few of which can be already stored. How do I store remaining ones in MongoDB in a matter of seconds, not minutes/hours?

Comment: unfortunately there is no other way as iterate documents and use update_one. I was thinking about bulk operations, but to use bulk.find.upsert you need to have this document in db first.

Comment: OK. Can bulk delete the documents from the list and then bulk insert them?

Comment: if you get full collection in to list - then you can just delete collection and insert , or delete by know ids (retrieved ones) and reinsert using insert_many.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) method and set the ordered option to `False`.

```
db_stock.insert_many(<list of documents>)
```

As mentioned in the *ordered* option documentation:

> *ordered* (optional): If True (the default) documents will be inserted on the server serially, in the order provided. If an error occurs all remaining inserts are aborted. If False, documents will be inserted on the server in arbitrary order, possibly in parallel, and all document inserts will be attempted.

Which means that insertion will continue even if there is duplicate key error.

Demo:

```
>>> c.insert_many([{'_id': 2}, {'_id': 3}])
<pymongo.results.InsertManyResult object at 0x7f5ca669ef30>
>>> list(c.find())
[{'_id': 2}, {'_id': 3}]
>>> try:
...     c.insert_many([{'_id': 2}, {'_id': 3}, {'_id': 4}, {'_id': 5}], ordered=False)
... except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError:
...     list(c.find())
... 
[{'_id': 2}, {'_id': 3}, {'_id': 4}, {'_id': 5}]
```

As you can see document with `_id` 4, 5 were inserted into the collection.

---

It worth noting that this is also possible in the shell using the [`insertMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) method. All you need is set the undocumented option `ordered` to `false`.

```
db.collection.insertMany(
    [ 
        { '_id': 2 }, 
        { '_id': 3 },
        { '_id': 4 }, 
        { '_id': 5 }
    ],
    { 'ordered': false }
)
```

Comment: @ORA600 Just to make the distinction clear, using "upserts" ( even with [bulk](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html) operations, and still the old interface for current pymongo ) means that you are still "looking up" the data prior to deciding whether to "insert" or not. The nature of the "lookup" means you never get duplicates, **however** it naturally comes with a "cost". Hence the suggestion to "insert_many" with `ordered=False` ( can still do the same thing with "bulk" ) does not have that "lookup" overhead. Hences it's the "fastest", which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

With [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) you can do this, though I'm not sure what the pymongo command for it is, here's the straight mongodb query:

```
db.products.insert([
  { _id: 11, item: "pencil", qty: 50, type: "no.2" },
  { item: "pen", qty: 20 },
  { item: "eraser", qty: 25 }
])
```

Comment: this is not answer for this particular question, as it states "bulk UPSERT"

Comment: His question says **insert** in both title and question body.

Comment: "en masse" means bulk :-)