# Update with upsert, but only update if date field of document in db is less than updated document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having a bit of an issue trying to come up with the logic for this. So, what I want to do is:

- Bulk update a bunch of posts to my remote MongoDB instance BUT
- If update, only update if `lastModified` field on the remote collection is less than `lastModified` field in the same document that I am about to update/insert

Basically, I want to update my list of documents if they have been modified since the last time I updated them.
I can think of two brute force ways to do it...

First, querying my entire collection, trying to manually remove and replace the documents that match the criteria, add the new ones, and then mass insert everything back to the remote collection after deleting everything in remote.

Second, query each item and then deciding, if there is one in remote, if I want to update it or no. This seems like it would be very tasking when dealing with remote collections.

If relevant, I am working on a NodeJS environment, using the `mondodb` npm package for database operations.

Comment: Are you updating the documents with a value from another collection?

Comment: Nope, I'm gathering the values from an http call to an external service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`bulkWrite`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite)** API to carry out the updates based on the logic you specified as it handles this better.

For example, the following snippet shows how to go about this assuming you already have the data from the web service you need to update the remote collection with:

```
mongodb.connect(mongo_url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else {
        var mongo_remote_collection = db.collection("remote_collection_name");

        /* data is from http call to an external service or ideally
           place this within the service callback
        */
        mongoUpsert(mongo_remote_collection, data, function() {
            db.close();
        })
    }
})

function mongoUpsert(collection, data_array, cb) {      
    var ops = data_array.map(function(data) {
        return {
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { 
                    "_id": data._id, // or any other filtering mechanism to identify a doc
                    "lastModified": { "$lt": data.lastModified }
                },
                "update": { "$set": data },
                "upsert": true
            }
        };
    });

    collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
        // do something with result
    });

    return cb(false);
}
```

---

If the data from the external service is huge then consider sending the writes to the server in batches of 500 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 500 requests.

For bulk operations MongoDB imposes a [default internal limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) of 1000 operations per batch and so the choice of 500 documents is good in the sense that you have some control over the batch size rather than let MongoDB impose the default, i.e. for larger operations in the magnitude of > 1000 documents. So for the above case in the first approach one could just write all the array at once as this is small but the 500 choice is for larger arrays.

```
var ops = [],
    counter = 0;

data_array.forEach(function(data) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { 
                "_id": data._id,
                "lastModified": { "$lt": data.lastModified }
            },
            "update": { "$set": data },
            "upsert": true
        }
    });
    counter++;

    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
            // do something with result
        });
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (counter % 500 != 0) {
    collection.bulkWrite(ops, function(err, r) {
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, documents that are found with an ID but lastModified conditional is not met (lastModified of local is less than lastModified of remote), will still be inserted in the collection, will they not? Since they do not fall on the filter parameters

Comment: Yes, the `{ upsert: true }` method guarantees that. Removing the option will mean if documents that are found with an ID but `lastModified` conditional is not met then the update does not take place. With `{ upsert: true }` if the query is not satisfied then it will insert the document.

Comment: This is an issue, what I am hoping to do is to insert if there is no ID match, but not insert if the local lastModified is less that remote lastModified. Basically, the filters would have different actions if one is passed or the other one.

Comment: I can't write a well explained answer now, so I am leaving this as comment.:)  What you need here is the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) update operator.

Comment: @Styvane But [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max) will only update ONLY the value of the `lastModified` field to a specified value from the other collection if the specified value is greater than the current value of the field. What about the other fields?

Comment: Humm! Good question, I did not think of that. In this case `$max` will not be useful but instead, all you need to set the  `ordered`  option of `bulkWrite` to false to [avoiding the operations to stop after a duplication key error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083247/how-to-continue-insertion-after-duplicate-key-error-using-pymongo) and do everything in  a`try/catch` block, handling the exception appropriately.

Comment: Wait a sec, if "lastModified of local is less than lastModified of remote", the local doc will NOT be inserted in this case, because mongo will throw a duplicate key error, right? The filter conditional is not met, due to "upsert: true" mongo will try to insert a doc with _id, the insert will fail because a doc with that _id already exists.