# How do I skip already inserted documents and only insert new documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have a unique `_id` for every document. So when a document with the same `_id` which is already imported, I get a duplicate error.

How can I skip already inserted `_id`'s?

```
if already inserted:
ignore and go to next.
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the structure of your document ?

Comment: I wrote it in the initial post, but a moderator removed the information. 

I have used a week now searching the web and trying different approaches like upsert. But I don't want to update documents. I only want to insert documents that does not already exists.

---------------------------------
Also I don't see how this is a duplicate question when it does not exist.
At least redirect to the duplicate thread @styvane if you mean this is a duplicate of an existing question....

Comment: Hi @aquatic7, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087171/3100115) and let me know if it doesn't give you the expected behavior, in which case should consider to edit your question and tell us why it didn't work and I will be happy to reopen your question and possibly provide you with an answer.