# insertMany only if key with value does not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using insertMany to insert documents collected from the spotify api, with the below structure:

```js
{
  spotify_id: "6400dnyeDyD2mIFHfkwHXN",
  name: "Pablo Honey",
  ...
}
```

Using:

```js
  db.collection.insertMany(albums)
```

(where albums is an array containing objects of the above structure)

On subsequent calls the same operation runs, but I would like to only insert *new* documents, i.e not those where `spotify_id` already exists in the database

Comment: You can do this with an unordered bulk write.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb: insert if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a unique index on `spotify_id`, then you can use that plus `insertMany` with `ordered = false` to keep inserting even if a dupe is found.  You'll want to double check the errors of course:

```
db.foo.drop();
db.foo.createIndex({"spotify_id":1}, {unique:true});

function loadEm(r) {
    try {
        rc = db.foo.insertMany(r, {ordered:false});
    } catch(e) {
    // Check for expected dupe errors:                                          
    e.getWriteErrors().forEach(function(err) {
        if(err.code != 11000) {
                    // real error!                                                  
                    throw e;
                }
            });
    }
}

loadEm(
[
 {spotify_id: "A", name: "foo"},
 {spotify_id: "B", name: "bar"}
]
       );


loadEm(
[
 {spotify_id: "A", name: "foo"},
 {spotify_id: "B", name: "bar"},
 {spotify_id: "C", name: "corn"},
 {spotify_id: "C", name: "dog"},
 {spotify_id: "D", name: "zap"}
]
       );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the method I used in the end