# Pymongo Not inserting full document on update_one

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a lot of documents to update and I want to write a timestamp initially and then an update timestamp when there are duplicates.
So I found this answer and am attempting it for MongoDB 6.0
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17533368/3300927

I also store in my model the variable to use when looking for duplicates as `searchable`

If a query has no `searchable` then I insert it without checking and add a timestamp, then take the results and add a timestamp:

```py
data_inserted = collection.insert_many(results)
for doc_id in data_inserted.inserted_ids:
    collection.update_many(
        filter={'_id': doc_id},
        update={'$set': {'insert_date': now, }, },
        upsert=True)
```

No issues there:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "321654987654"
  },
  "IR NUMBER": "ABC784",
  "Plate": " ",
  "Plate State": " ",
  "Make": "TOYOTA",
  "Model": "TACOMA",
  "Style": "  ",
  "Color": "SIL /    ",
  "Year": "2008",
  "insert_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1660000808176"
    }
  }
}
```

If there is a `searchable` I attempt to look for it. What I get in MongoDB is only the `searchable` field with the timestamp:

```py
# q_statement.searchable == 'IR NUMBER'

for document in results:
    collection.update_one(
        filter={q_statement.searchable: document[q_statement.searchable], },
        update={'$setOnInsert': {'insert_date': now, }, '$set': {'update_date': now, }},
        upsert=True)
```

result:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62f19d981aa321654987"
  },
  "IR NUMBER": "ABC784",
  "insert_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1660001688126"
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the `pymongo.results.UpdateResult` by changing the `for` loop contents to `updates = collection.update_one( ... print(updates.raw_result)` shows ~ 10k results like:

```py
  {
    "n": 1,
    "upserted": ObjectId("62f27ae21aa62fbfa734f01d"),
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1.0,
    "updatedExisting": False
  },
  {
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1.0,
    "updatedExisting": True
  },
  {
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1.0,
    "updatedExisting": True
  }
```

(python==3.10.3, Django==4.0.4, pymongo==4.2.0)

Comment: `collection.update_one` returns a[`pymongo.results.UpdateResult`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult).  Perhaps if you printed its properties for each `update_one`, the behavior would be more clear.

Comment: Changed the for loop to 
---
                    updates = collection.update_one(
                      ...
                    print(updates.raw_result)
---
and get 10k lines like this:
---
{'n': 1, 'upserted': ObjectId('62f27ae21aa62fbfa734f01d'), 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': False}
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  If `results` was initially inserted into `collection`, based on your `filter` search criteria, how is it possible for an `upsert` to happen later?  Wouldn't there always be a match? ... or is another user/process also updating the collection that would delete/modify the initial `results` insertion?

Comment: I'm pulling joining data from MSSQL and putting it into MongoDB. The MSSQL statements are in the Django Query Model ( as q_statement). If there is a q_statement.searchable it uses the update_one for loop and filter code in question every time to insert and update. If there is no q_statement.searchable, then it uses the insert_many which has no issues (but will make duplicates next time it runs). Do you think I shouldn't enter a searchable till after doing the insert_many the first time and the update thereafter? I was hoping to write it to handle an initial write and subsequent updates.

Comment: I think I understand a bit better now.  Thanks for the explanation. I do have some more questions though.  Do you expect `searchable` to be unique in the collection?  If not, won't `update_one` randomly select a document to update?  I believe the reason for the `searchable` documents being so sparse on insertion is because the `update_one` doesn't reference anything other than `searchable` in `document` (from `results`).  One of the options that I would consider is to make all modifications to `results` in `python` first, and then do the insertion/update.

Comment: The `update_one` creates a new document for each for loop (as expected) but only entered the IR and date field, not the other vehicle info(not expected). What I want is. If the document exists, change `update_date` to now. else create a new document with ALL the fields. and I have no idea why all the fields aren't coming.

Comment: I don't completely understand your update strategy, but you might try `update={'$setOnInsert': document | {'insert_date': now}, '$set': {'update_date': now, }}`.

Comment: That includes that document and the date fields... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `"upsert"` a full document and additional fields using `python`, you can use MongoDB's `"$setOnInsert"` with a `python` merged dictionary.

From the [python library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), here's how you merge dictionaries.  (It's similar to MongoDB's [`"$mergeObjects"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/).)

```
d | other

Create a new dictionary with the merged keys and values of d and other,
which must both be dictionaries. The values of other take priority
when d and other share keys.
```

So, to insert the full `document`, using your python code, it just needs a minor addition - merge `document` with your other object.

```py
...
update={'$setOnInsert': document | {'insert_date': now}, '$set': {'update_date': now, }}
...
```