Consistently perform concurrent write operations in REST API that uses MongoDB
I'm writing a REST API using Flask and MongoDB (I use pymongo to interact with the database). I'm having an issue that seems to be related to race conditions. I have been able to reproduce my use case through a minimal reproducible example which I have shown below.
Consider the following collection:
[
  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'books': [
      {
        'title': 'Book 1',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 100,
        'date-bought': '2024-09-23'
      }
    ]
  }
]

After the request shown in the first code block below has finished, the collection should look as in the second code block.
PUT /name/Mike/books/Book 2
Content-Type: application/json
{'minutes-spent-reading': 40}

[
  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'books': [
      {
        'title': 'Book 1',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 100,
        'date-bought': '2024-09-23'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Book 2',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 40,
      }
    ]
  }
]

After the request shown in the first code block has finished, the collection should look as in the second code block.
PUT /name/Mike/books/Book 2
Content-Type: application/json
{'date-bought': '2024-09-26'}

[
  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'books': [
      {
        'title': 'Book 1',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 100,
        'date-bought': '2024-09-23'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Book 2',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 40,
        'date-bought': '2024-09-26'
      }
    ]
  }
]

However, using my REST API results in the following:
[
  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'books': [
      {
        'title': 'Book 1',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 100,
        'date-bought': '2024-09-23'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Book 2',
        'minutes-spent-reading': 40
      },
      {
        'title': 'Book 2',
        'date-bought': '2024-09-26'
      }
    ]
  }
]

I have been able to reproduce the way my REST API performs the PUT operation with this minimal reproducible example:
import threading
import pymongo
import time
import json

def put_book_2_minutes_spend_reading(value):
  # Find book in the array of books
  book = db.experiment.find_one({
    'name': 'Mike',
    'books.title': 'Book 2'
  })
  # We use time.sleep(1) to simulate that, for some reason, the
  # computer took 1 second at this step.
  time.sleep(1)
  # If the book doesn't exist in the array of books, insert a new
  # object in the array.
  if book == None:
    db.experiment.find_one_and_update({
      'name': 'Mike',
    }, {
      '$push': {
        'books': {
          'title': 'Book 2',
          'minutes-spent-reading': value
        }
      }
    })
  else:
    # If the book exists in the array of books, set the key in the
    # existing book.
    db.experiment.find_one_and_update({
      'name': entity_id
    }, {
      '$set': {
        'books.$[book].minutes-spent-reading': value
      }
    }, array_filters = [{'book.title': 'Book 2'}])

def put_book_2_date_bought(value):
  book = db.experiment.find_one({
    'name': 'Mike',
    'books.title': 'Book 2'
  })
  # We use time.sleep(1) to simulate that, for some reason, the
  # computer took 1 second at this step.
  time.sleep(1)
  # If the book doesn't exist in the array of books, insert a new
  # object in the array.
  if book == None:
    db.experiment.find_one_and_update({
      'name': 'Mike',
    }, {
      '$push': {
        'books': {
          'title': 'Book 2',
          'date-bought': value
        }
      }
    })
  else:
    # If the book exists in the array of books, set the key in the
    # existing book.
    db.experiment.find_one_and_update({
      'name': 'Mike'
    }, {
      '$set': {
        'books.$[book].date-bought': value
      }
    }, array_filters = [{'book.title': 'Book 2'}])

db = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['experiment']
db.experiment.delete_many({})
# Sample item
db.experiment.insert_one({
  'name': 'Mike',
  'books': [
    {
      'title': 'Book 1',
      'minutes-spent-reading': 100,
      'date-bought': '2024-09-23'
    }
  ]
})

t1 = threading.Thread(target=put_book_2_minutes_spend_reading, args=[40])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=put_book_2_date_bought, args=['2024-01-20'])

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print(json.dumps(list(db.experiment.find({}, {"_id": 0})), indent=2))

The Python code shown above prints the following:
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Book 1",
        "minutes-spent-reading": 100,
        "date-bought": "2024-09-23"
      },
      {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "minutes-spent-reading": 40
      },
      {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "date-bought": "2024-01-20"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I would expect these results:
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Book 1",
        "minutes-spent-reading": 100,
        "date-bought": "2024-09-23"
      },
      {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "minutes-spent-reading": 40,
        "date-bought": "2024-01-20"
      }
    ]
  }
]

My question is: How to avoid MongoDB creating two books with the same title when there can be concurrent requests that set different keys for a book?

Sidenote
Please don't question the example's database schema since its main purpose is to explain a scenario in a more complex database schema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists

The solution is to use a single atomic operation in MongoDB to ensure that when two operations operate on the same document, one is run after the other. Thus, avoiding conflicts when the user triggers multiple write operations with milliseconds of difference.
Retrieved from https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.

Retrieved from https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-atomic-operation

An atomic operation is a write operation that either completes entirely or doesn't complete at all. For distributed transactions, which involve writes to multiple documents, all writes to each document must succeed for the transaction to succeed. Atomic operations cannot partially complete. See Atomicity and Transactions.

The following code was based on this answer:
import threading
import pymongo
import time
import json

def put_book_2_minutes_spent_reading(value):
  name = 'Mike'
  title = 'Book 2'
  db.experiment.update_one(
    {'name': name},
    [
      {
        '$set': {
          'books': {
            '$cond': [
              { '$in': [title, "$books.title"] },
              {
                '$map': {
                  'input': "$books",
                    'in': {
                      '$cond': [
                        { '$eq': [title, "$$this.title"] },
                        {
                          '$mergeObjects': [
                            '$$this',
                            {'minutes-spent-reading': value}
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$this"
                      ]
                    }
                }
              },
              {
                '$concatArrays': [
                  "$books",
                  [
                    {
                      'title': title,
                      'minutes-spent-reading': value
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  )

def put_book_2_date_bought(value):
  name = 'Mike'
  title = 'Book 2'
  db.experiment.update_one(
    {'name': name},
    [
      {
        '$set': {
          'books': {
            '$cond': [
              { '$in': [title, "$books.title"] },
              {
                '$map': {
                  'input': "$books",
                    'in': {
                      '$cond': [
                        { '$eq': [title, "$$this.title"] },
                        {
                          '$mergeObjects': [
                            '$$this',
                            {'date-bought': value}
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$this"
                      ]
                    }
                }
              },
              {
                '$concatArrays': [
                  "$books",
                  [
                    {
                      'title': title,
                      'date-bought': value
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  )

db = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['experiment']
db.experiment.delete_many({})
db.experiment.insert_one({
  'name': 'Mike',
  'books': [
    {
      'title': 'Book 1',
      'minutes-spent-reading': 100,
      'date-bought': '2024-09-23'
    }
  ]
})

t1 = threading.Thread(target=put_book_2_minutes_spent_reading, args=[40])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=put_book_2_date_bought, args=['2024-01-20'])

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print(json.dumps(list(db.experiment.find({}, {"_id": 0})), indent=2))

[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Book 1",
        "minutes-spent-reading": 100,
        "date-bought": "2024-09-23"
      },
      {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "minutes-spent-reading": 40,
        "date-bought": "2024-01-20"
      }
    ]
  }
]

